# AWS Active Directory Connector and Azure Active Directory Domain Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to replicate the steps in this [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/desktop-and-application-streaming/add-your-workspaces-to-azure-ad-using-azure-active-directory-domain-services/). However, When I get to the step where I create the ad connector, it fails with the following error:

> Connectivity issues detected: DNS unavailable (TCP Port 53) for IP 10.0.0.4, DNS unavailable (TCP Port 53) for IP 10.0.0.5. Please ensure that the listed ports are available and retry the operation

I am very proficient with AWS. However, I'm struggling with Azure and feel I may have misconfigured something. I have carried out the following steps thus far:

In Azure, I used an existing resource group and created "Azure AD Domain Services" instance using default configuration

**Basics**

- Name: sy******k.com
- Subscription: Pay-As-You-Go
- Resource Group:
- Default Region: UK South
- SKU: Standard  Forest type: User

Network

- Virtual network: (new) aadds-vnet
- Subnet: (new) aadds-subnet
- Subnet Address: 10.0.0.0/24
- Network Security Group: (new) aadds-nsg

I created a site to site vpn connection with azure virtual network. However, I am not sure about this step in the post: "The tunnels must be configured to allow traffic from your AADDS endpoints and the Subnets" How exactly do I do this?

In AWS VPC cidr is 10.1.0.0/16 and both tunnels between AWS VPC and Azure Virtual Network are up and connected. I tried to contact the post author: "Justin Stokes" directly but can't find any emails for him. I cannot find a single online guide on how to set this up step by step along with the site to site ipsec setup. It would be very very helpful if someone can provide a video tutorial for this step by step from A-Z instead of leaving a chunk of the steps out of the guide.

The troubleshooting guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ad_connector_troubleshooting.html) suggest that the firewall i.e. network security group is not allowing port 53TCP/UDP inbound for AD Connector. But I updated the networks security group as a test with a rule to allow any source, any destination and any port and still I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not the expert in both AWS and Azure but succeeded to setup VPN using this [guide](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-connect-between-azure-and-aws-with-managed-services-4b03ec334e8a).
Then set up AD Connector and had to take tip of creating DHCP Option set from this [post](https://theithollow.com/2018/04/23/aws-directory-service-ad-connector/).

AD Connector created successfully now. EC2 instances launch with correct DNS server and suffix however they are not joined to AD, that's where I am now. If you have anything or completed this setup, please share.